# Elastic search - Locate matched word line no in paragraph

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene

In our application we use ElasticSearch as search engine. It works perfectly well and most of our data are textual paragraphs. We also able to highlight keywords equally well in search results.

On our web page, we are limited to show only top 1000 characters of matched results, so we trim data after 1000 characters.

Now the issue is, for some results Keyword highlight not appearing since it is down into lengthy text and getting trimmed.

So my question is, Does ES provides any option where it tells us index of matching keywords for each search results? any other workaround or alternative?

Let me know if needed more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api in elastic search which gives index of matched words
There is a [custom plugin highlighter (plugin)](https://github.com/wikimedia/search-highlighter).

You will need to adjust it to 7.x

There is a discussion [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/fetching-position-of-keyword-in-matched-document/94291/4) on it for further reference

A sample query from above discussion link

```
{
    "_source": ["content"],
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : { "content" : "test keyword" }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "pre_tags" : ["<b>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</b>"],
        "fields" : {
            "content" : {
                "fragment_size" : 30, 
                "number_of_fragments" : 10, 
                "type": "experimental",
                "options": {"return_offsets": true}
            }
        },
        "order" : "score"
    }
}
```